# Rails Active Record Has Many Association Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning rails right now and noticed this issue when I ran rake db:seed. I'm honestly not sure what the issue is because everything seems to run fine and all the associations seem to be working as well.

Error Message:

```
rake aborted! ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) "author" or :author in model Post. Try 'has_many :author, :through => :post, :source => <name>'. Is it one of user, category, comments, comment_users, likes, or like_users?
/home/houtai/hr.glass/ourz/db/seeds.rb:102:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Here is an example of my seeds:

```
User.create!({
  first_name: 'Mark',
  last_name: 'Wong',
  bio: 'bla',
  email: 'mark@gmail.com',
  password: 'test',
  password_confirmation: 'test',
  profile_pic: 'http://houtaiwong.com/img/profile.jpg'
  })

User.create!({
  first_name: 'Hou',
  last_name: 'Wong',
  bio: 'bla',
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
  password: 'test',
  password_confirmation: 'test',
  profile_pic: 'https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/alicia-vikander-the-danish-girl.jpg'
})

Category.create!({
  name: 'Music'
})

Category.create!({
  name: 'Blog'
})

Category.create!({
  name: 'Video'
})

Category.create!({
  name: 'Picture'
  })

Post.create!({
  title: 'Music',
  content: 'text',
  author: User.find_by(first_name: 'Mark').id,
  category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Music').id,
  end_time: '12/1/2016',
  image: 'https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/alicia-vikander-the-danish-girl.jpg'
})
```

Here are my associations:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  authenticates_with_sorcery!

  # attr_accessor :remote_image_url, :first_name, :last_name, :bio, :emaily, :profile_pic

  validates :password, length: { minimum: 3 }, if: -> { new_record? || changes[:crypted_password] }
  validates :password, confirmation: true, if: -> { new_record? || changes[:crypted_password] }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: -> { new_record? || changes[:crypted_password] }

  validates :email, uniqueness: true

  has_many :posts, foreign_key: :author

  has_many :active_relationships,  class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower

  has_many :comments
  has_many :comment_posts, through: :comments, source: 'post'

  has_many :likes
  has_many :like_posts, through: :likes, source: 'post'
```

Post:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'time'

  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :author
  belongs_to :category

  has_many :comments
  has_many :comment_users, through: :comments, source: 'user'

  has_many :likes
  has_many :like_users, through: :likes, source: 'user'

  validates :title, presence: true
```

Comment: But the error message has nothing to do with the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your relation in Post model you have:

```
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :author
```

This means that the rails relation is user not author, but because you have the foreign_key set to author, when ActiveRecord looks in the database it will use the author_id field.

So in your seeds where you have:

```
Post.create!({
  title: 'Music',
  content: 'text',
  author: User.find_by(first_name: 'Mark').id,
  category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Music').id,
  end_time: '12/1/2016',
  image: 'https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/alicia-vikander-the-danish-girl.jpg'
})
```

the author key will not be recognised, because you have stated the relation as user.

Two possible solutions are change your seeds to:

```
Post.create!({
  title: 'Music',
  content: 'text',
  user: User.find_by(first_name: 'Mark').id,
  category_id: Category.find_by(name: 'Music').id,
  end_time: '12/1/2016',
  image: 'https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/alicia-vikander-the-danish-girl.jpg'
})
```

or change your relation in Post to:

```
belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
```

This should solve the `Could not find the source association(s) "author" or :author in model Post` part however you have a lot of relations and through tables going on there and more info may be required in order to get the whole picture.